# Break user input in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keyup

Is there any way to break user input?
ex. A user will type its physical address in a textbox, 
when he enter his value I want to insert '-' character
so that when user will type '002255667788' 
I can format it automatically '00-22-55-66-77-88'.

Can I do that in keypress?thank you.

Comment: Is it always every 2 characters?

Comment: yes. It's a physical address of a computer system.

Comment: Yes, you can do it on keyup, keydown, or keypress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery plugin Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

It's pretty simple to use, just add how to you want to format your number:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#your_id').mask('11-11-11-11-11');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moratto/sXGTd/)** with example.

Comment: typeerror:$(...).mask is not a function.

Comment: Yes, sure, you need to download the jQuery Plugin http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can listen to the blur event and format the value of the input:

```
$('#your_input').on('blur', function(){
    //clean the non numeric values
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')
    //place the dashes
    .replace(/(\d{2})/g,'$1-')
})
```

You can also change the value on key events, but be careful to detect when it's `delete`, `enter`, and so on..